# Microsoft sync framework 2.1 does not support geometry

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

Does Microsoft sync framework 2.1 does support geometry?

I read that it doesn't although I don't understand why, since all the databases I'm using support spatial types.

Is there a work around?

Comment: How do you feel about XML and 1-to-1 tables?

Comment: Geometry data can be stored as type geom or as xml.  XML can be replicated but geom cannot (afaik).  Of course geom queries are faster and work better.  A 1-to-1 table is a way of splitting a table into two. One can contain replication-friendly columns and the other can store geom. Typically 1-to-1 tables indicate a bad design but are permissible when you are trying to overcome a technology limit.

Comment: Ah yes. Currently I'm using another column as text and that column will be used for sync.